# Why doesn't unity audio work with 4 channels

Tags: unity-game-engine, audio

I'm trying to figure out how to do multi channel audio in unity, and it looks like something isn't working correctly.

Here is my setup:

- Blank unity project (unity 2020.3.0f1)
- Set project settings > audio > default speaker mode to "Quad"
- Create a 4-channel audio clip with audacity (1 "click" on each channel, one at a time)
- Import the clip into unity with default settings
  [image: 4 channel audio asset preview]

I don't have an external sound card (yet) so I'm using VB-Cable as a virtual 4-channel output

VB-Cable provides a Control panel where I can see the levels for each channel.
Playing back the source file with quicktime, I can see the channel 1,2,3 and 4 levels moving as I expect.
However, playing back the imported audio clip in unity's asset preview merges channel 1 with 3, and 2 with 4. The same thing happens when playing the audio in-game.

Another setup I've tried is the same as above, but setting up my computer to use an "aggregate audio device":

- 2 outputs from my built-in output
- 2 outputs from VB-Cable
  [image: Aggregate audio device configuration]

(I also changed the VB-Cable settings to make it a 2-channel output, so that when combined with the built-in output, I get a 4-channel output device)

With this setup, playing back the clip in Quicktime or in the unity asset preview works as expected (I hear the channels 1 and 2 through the Built-in output and "see" the channels 3 and 4 on the VB-Cable control panel).
Playing the clip in-game however, only the channels 1,2 and 3 seem to work. Nothing happens on channel 4 (Using a unity audio mixer, I can see channels 1,2 and 3 "lighting up" but 4 stays silent)

I know changing audio config with unity opened is not guaranteed to work, so for every test I do, I quit and restart Unity.

I hope I've explained the issue properly. If not, [here is a zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hcIjoiYbWCpzCh8KhLfBIFjXiTo8o9ve/view?usp=sharing) containing the test unity project (including the 4 channel audio track), and screen recording of different tests I've made.

System:

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)
- MacOS 11.6.2
- 16GB RAM
- 2,8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i7